# Ancestry gem gives error "The scope body needs to be callable." in rails 4?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

models/message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "content"
  t.integer  "parent_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "ancestry"
end
```

after adding `has_ancestry` in model it gives error Argument Error.

> "The scope body needs to be callable."

Please help me

Thanks